# GFCI outlet - Why no green LED indicator?

Tags: gfci

Just installed new GFCI.  When I plug in a device it has power, then press test button and power drops out, then press reset button and power is back on.  Everything appears to work EXCEPT no green led indicator - why??

Comment: What make and model is said GFCI?

Comment: Personally, I don't like the indicator lights on everything. What should be a perfectly dark room isn't any more. But if it is **supposed** to have that green light (as opposed to "my old GFCI did, so this one should have one to") then if the light doesn't come on that is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is supposed to turn green and doesn't, it is faulty. Replace it.